# Does mapbox supports "Search by location" / geocoding autosuggestion feature in iOS ?

Tags: ios, autocomplete, geocoding, mapbox

Im currently working on mapbox iOS application. I wanted to know if we could use 'Search by location' feature in iOS application ?

Also is geocoding with autosuggestion is available for iOS SDK ?

I could not find any documentation as such. 
Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks, 
RD

Answer (score 0):

Yep, check out https://github.com/mapbox/MapboxGeocoder.swift. Works just like Apple's `CLGeocoder` and recently got support for points of information (business names; see https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/geocoding/).